# Retrieve data from multiple workbooks, all in the same selected folder?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to retrieve data from multiple Excel workbooks in a folder.
The files are not opened.
The workbooks are called: Business Case (1), Business Case (2)... (incrementally growing until ~50).

I need the data to do business analysis, and evaluate potential ideas.

I got it working until file nr. 11 with the "Indirect" function. It won't retrieve more data after 10+; so I started looking at VBA.

The first problem I ran into with VBA, is that lopping through Excel files, looks like it requires a "fixed" path (e.g.: c:\Users\Bonkers\Desktop\Folder.....). I want the master-data-retrieval-book to work on other PCs, so the path of the folder, needs to be "not limited" to my PC.

```vb
Function ChooseFolder(strTitle As String, fDtype) As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String

    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(fDtype)
    With fldr
        .Title = strTitle
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

NextCode:
    ChooseFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function

Sub datatransfer()

    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim targetfile As String
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

    targetfile = ChooseFolder("Please select the target file", msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    FolderPath = ChooseFolder("Please select the Folder path", msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    FilePath = FolderPath & "\Business Case (*.xls*)"

    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(targetfile) 'only need to open this once and leave open until execution is finished

    Filename = Dir(FilePath)

    Do While Filename <> "" ' need "<>" to say not equal to nothing

        wb2.Worksheets.Add After:=wb2.Worksheets(wb2.Worksheets.Count) 'add new sheet to paste data in target book

        Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & "\" & Filename)

        Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

        With wb1.Worksheets(1) 'best to qualify all objects and work directly with them
            lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lastcolumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            'pretty sure you want to add this A1, since it's a new blank sheet
            .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy _
                Destination:=wb2.Worksheets(wb2.Worksheets.Count).Range("A1")

        End With

        wb1.Close False 'assume no need to save changes to workbook you copied data from

        Filename = Dir

    Loop

    wb2.Close True 'no close and save master file

End Sub
```

Comment: I am afraid that we cannot understand too much from your question... Are all the workbooks in discussion already open? If not, what do you understand by "generic code" in terms of files and folder location? Should the desired code previously offer a dialog able to initially set the files folder and then the folder where the data `to be retrieved'? Then, how to retrieve data from 'multiple Excel workbooks' directly in a folder? Are there a workbook where to be collected the data in discussion? Should there be created a  new workbook where the data to be places? What did you try by your own?

Comment: What do you mean  by 'a "hard coded" path`?

Comment: Could you describe the whole process of the user's interaction with the code and post the code you got so far or the code closest to meet your requirements. You can [edit] your question at any time.

Comment: You could use an inputbox where you can place your path and then go from there. Skripts to loop through all files in a folder are available here on mass.

Comment: So.. The longer explanation.

I have say 20 business cases, in the same template, but with different numbers (Business Case (1) etc.) - They are all in the same folder.

I need to copy the data from all the workbooks, and into a master sheet, where i will then do som analysis on the data.

The problem is I need the folder which contains the business cases to be "any folder - Which the "Data Collection master sheet" is placed within.

Comment: The files are not open.

I would prefer the data was collected and then simply linked into the master file.

I thought i had solved the issued, using the "Indirect" function in Excel, but it stopped working after 10+, for some reason i cannot debug.

So now i am looking at VBA coding something

Comment: You still ask about 'the path being "dynamic"', but **only you know what this "dynamic" means**... I can see in your code that the first (working) function is not called by the "datatransfer" `Sub`. Isn't what the function returns what you need when say "dynamic"? If not, please try better describe the meaning of this concept...

Comment: It seems that you are using a third workbook that contains the code. How will you determine the target file? What is the relation between it and the folder containing the source files? There has to be some logic. If you use the folder picker for the source files, then you should know where the target file is located. On the other hand, if you know the path of the target file, you should know the location of the source folder. For example, if the source files are in `C:\Test\Source` then your target file may be in `C:\Test` which is the parent folder of the source folder.

Comment: @FaneDuru - I think you nailed part of my issue. The first one: How do make the link between the folderpicker, and make the "data retrieval" take that one?

VBasic2008 - I would like to have the VBA retrieval and retrived data in the same file. - So if the link here is missing, its because i havent adressed this issue yet. (Due not i am 100% new to VBA, and the learning curve is a bit steep =) )

Comment: In case of the `targetfile` do you want receiving its folder (knowing its name) or the file full name?

Comment: @FaneDuru - I believe i want to know the folders name. So i can tell the next bit of code "Where to retrieve data from".

Comment: So, do you (your colleagues) know the name of the `targetfile`?

Comment: All target files to retrieve data from are called: Business Case (X).

So, e.g. Business Case (1), Business Case (2), Etc. Utilizing the renaming feature in Windows, which names all the files the same, with a number in the name increasing +1 pr. file.

Comment: Please, test the adapted function I posted. It is able to return the folder path and the target file full name, too. Isn't it be convenient?

Comment: But don't all the files to retrieve data exist in the same folder? Should I understand that there are also other files then the ones you need (having the name respecting the pattern you show us)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to dynamically set the files folder and the target file you can use the next adapted function:

```
Function ChooseFolder(strTitle As String, fDtype) As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String

    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(fDtype)
    With fldr
        .Title = strTitle
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

NextCode:
    ChooseFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Then, in the processing `Sub` you may call it in the next way:

```
targetfile = ChooseFolder("Please select the target file", msoFileDialogFilePicker)
FolderPath = ChooseFolder("Please select the Folder path", msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

FilePath = folderPath & "\Business Case (*.xls*"
```

**Edited**:

Please, use this updated code. It will copy all the range **as it is**. Since, I do not know if the content of the all involved workbooks looks the same, I tried designing the code to behave as for the similar structures:

```
Sub datatransfer()
    Dim FolderPath As String, FilePath As String, Filename As String, targetfile As String
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, astrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long
    
    FolderPath = ChooseFolder("Please select the Folder path", msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    targetfile = ChooseFolder("Please select the target file", msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    FilePath = FolderPath & "\Business Case (*.xls*" 'you wrongly copied this line...

    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(targetfile)
    Filename = Dir(FilePath)

    Do While Filename <> ""
        wb2.Worksheets.Add After:=wb2.Worksheets(wb2.Worksheets.Count) 'add new sheet to paste data in target book

        Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & "\" & Filename)

        With wb1.Worksheets(1) 'best to qualify all objects and work directly with them
            lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row
            lastcolumn = .UsedRange.Columns.Count + .UsedRange.Column

            .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy _
                Destination:=wb2.Worksheets(wb2.Worksheets.Count).Range("A2")
        End With

        wb1.Close False 'assume no need to save changes to workbook you copied data from

        Filename = Dir
    Loop
    wb2.Close True 'no close and save master file
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: I get an error when trying to input the target file and folderpath. - Its 100% an error 40. Could you direct me in where to change this bit?

Current, after the Dim wbl As Workbook, i put it in. it crashes

Comment: @Michael Madsen "an error" does not say anything... What error and on what code line?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the short error comment - it posted my reply before I could explain =)

Comment: It is targeting the "FilePath As String" saying: Statement invalide, outside type of block?

Comment: @Michael Madsen Where do you find "FilePath As String"  in the code I  pasted? It only should mean that you have such a code line outside a `Sub/Function`... You should copy the new function as it is, change the name of your existing one (Adding a suffix...) and replace the three existing code lines with the ones I suggested, in the processing sub...

Comment: @Michael Madsen: Still alive? I will leave my office in some minutes and I would like to know if you understand the meaning of the code I pasted and also that I understood your real need. If I didn't, I still have time to adapt solution according to what I will be able to understand from your new clarifications...

Comment: Still Alive, just had to rush for lunch. I will try it, and come back =)

Comment: I have updated the code above, with my current code.

Comment: @Michael Madsen: OK, you did it, but should I understand that the code still does not work as you need? If it doesn't, **what problem do you still face using the adapted code**? In about 5 to 10 minutes I will not be available, anymore. I will be back in about three hours...

Comment: it still does not work. 
The first part, of folder selction i can run in the VBA coder (F11) - but the last part - Data transfer is still not retriving any data. (I also know i have not pointed it towards any specific cells in the business cases, so i am trying to figure out, how to do that.)

Comment: @Michael Madsen: "It does not work" does not say too much... Let us take it in small steps: Does the above solution assure the dynamic way of folder and target file full name, as you required in your question? Then, you should replace `Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Filename)` with `Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & "\" & Filename)`. Does your code return an error? If yes, what error, on which line? If not, what does it do instead of what you want?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me :)! - when I change the code to what you have written, i get a "Compile error" :" Statement invalid outside type block. And it highlights the line "FilePath As String".

Comment: Hey ... Now we are getting somewhere. I edited the code, adding Dim on all the files, and now it asks for a file name and a folder afterwords. I quess that means i now have the path system in function... (am i right?)

Now the part of retrieving data, and putting it into the recieving data sheet.. I will update the code in the original post.

Comment: @Michael Madsen: I am afraid that I cannot keep the step with your way of putting the problem. If not confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion? If yes, you can use a transfer site. [This one](https://easyupload.io/) is free and easy to be used.

Comment: I can not send it out to the world :( - Could a Teams/Skype call be made? - I have tried to reach out to you, through teams, using your private email form your profile here :)

Comment: @Michael Madsen: If you cannot share it, sending on my private mail, I am afraid I cannot help, anymore. I wish you all the best! I cannot understand from your explanations where the problem is... Do you know how to run the code line by line? If yes, try doing it and see where the problem appears. Or if the code does not go where it should.

Comment: I can send an empty file in a dummy =) - Check your email .

Comment: I do not need any data in the workbook. I only want seeing why you say that the code does not work. But, to be the code I suggested...

Comment: @Michael Madsen: So, should 'Portofolio tool.xlsm' workbook be considered as target file? If not, should I create a new workbook and consider it the target file?

Comment: @Michael Madsen: You do not say anything... So, I created a new workbook and tried using it as target file. You firstly wrongly copied from my code. It should be: `FilePath = FolderPath & "\Business Case (*.xls*"`. You put a useless extra parenthesis at the end. Then, you wrongly try calculate `lastrow` and `lastcolumn`. Calculating on the first column and first row, which are empty, they will be 1. Did you make this code, or you took it from the internet without understanding what is it about? I cannot understand what you want copying. Do you want copying everything from the first worksheet?

Comment: thanks for keep up with me :)
Yes. Portfolio tool is the target file.

Comment: I blankly admit i searched for the coding bits, and am still learning how to piece them together!

I want to copy data from the Business cases, into the Portfolio tool. 
I dont want everything i want specific cells, from each business case.
(See the Portfolio tool i send you, it contains the target cells i want to get data from)